# How to change color of phone number default phone book application in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I want to change color of phone number in default phone book application.Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify the behaviour of Apple applications other than through the settings. Unfortunately there is no setting for the color of phone numbers.

If you are displaying the phone numbers in your own UITableViewCell within your own application, this is a whole different story.